# How Can I Unfold This Event to an Observable Sequence?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I'm trying to write an Add-In for Outlook, and one of the events I'm using is `ItemsEvents_Event.ItemChange` - and its handler's signature takes an  `Object` as a parameter (the item that changed):

```
items.ItemChange += CalendarItems_ItemChange;

private void CalendarItems_ItemChange(object anItem) {...}
```

How would I use `Observable.FromEvent` or `Observable.FromEventPattern` to create an observable sequence from this event "stream" instead of attaching/detaching the event as usual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `FromEvent` conversion overload to tell Rx how it should interpret your event:

```
IObservable<TEventArgs> FromEvent<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(Func<Action<TEventArgs>, TDelegate> conversion, 
                                                         Action<TDelegate> addHandler, 
                                                         Action<TDelegate> removeHandler);
```

In your case it would look like:

```
var source = Observable.FromEvent<ItemsEvents_ItemEventChangeHandler, object>(
  emit => new ItemsEvents_ItemEventChangeHandler((obj) => emit(obj)),
  h => items.ItemChange += h,
  h => items.ItemChange -= h);
```

Similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31898177/2521865)